# Передать сигнал в виджет qt из другого объекта

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Qt5 c++. Про сигналы и слоты написано много, но мне так и не понятно как передать значение через сигнал на объект на форме ui. Тот вариант который я прописал сейчас не работает.

Что имеем:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();


private slots:
  void on_pushButtonStart_clicked();
  void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

#ifndef TRANSPORTMAIL_H
#define TRANSPORTMAIL_H

#include <QObject>

class TransportMail : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit TransportMail(QObject *parent = 0);

  QString transport(QString, QString);
  QString email_transport (QString, QString);
  QString transport_email (QString, QString);
  QString email (int i);

private:
  int pisem = 0;
signals:
  void muttrc_switch ();
  void sendmail_sig (int);
};

#endif // TRANSPORTMAIL_H

/// mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include "headers.h"
#include "configmuttrc.h"
#include "transportmail.h"
#include "statistics.h"
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  TransportMail *tm = new TransportMail;

  QObject::connect(tm, SIGNAL (sendmail_sig(int)), ui->lcdNumberSendMail, SLOT (display(int)));

}
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStart_clicked()
{
  TransportMail tm;
  tm.email_transport ("/home/alexandr/mutt/mail_shablon_dgis.html", "");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}



/// transport.cpp

#include "transportmail.h"
#include "configmuttrc.h"
#include "statistics.h"
#include "headers.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


TransportMail::TransportMail(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString  TransportMail::email_transport (QString message, QString subscription)
{
  TransportMail t;

  int i, j;
  i = 1, j = 10; 
  while (i<j)
  {
      emit sendmail_sig (i); 
      Helper::msleep(1800);
  i++;
  }
}

QString  TransportMail::email (int i)
{
---
}
QString TransportMail::transport(QString email, QString file)
{
---
}
QString TransportMail::transport_email (QString adress, QString file)
{
---
}
```

Comment: У Вас какие-то забавные пробелы в понимании C++ && Qt signal,slots paradigm.
Почитайте как Шлее, думаю все встанет на место.

Comment: благодарю за наводку, буду изучать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStart_clicked()
{
    TransportMail tm;
    tm.email_transport ("/home/alexandr/mutt/mail_shablon_dgis.html", "");
}
```

Заменить на:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStart_clicked()
{
    TransportMail *tm = new TransportMail();
    QObject::connect(tm, SIGNAL (sendmail_sig(int)), ui->lcdNumberSendMail, SLOT (display(int)));
    tm->email_transport ("/home/alexandr/mutt/mail_shablon_dgis.html", "");
}
```

Правда в данном случае мы создаем объект на куче и нигде его не удаляем - будут утечки памяти.

Comment: Есть мнение, что для избежания утечки достаточно передать в родительский конструктор указатель на экземпляр QMainWindow, например.

Comment: Я б заметил что не мнение, но правило :)
На этом и стоит QObject идея, создавать дерево объектов, с тем чтобы удаление было корректным.

Comment: И кстати, при утвержденном, как правильный, ответе, при каждом нажатии на кнопку будет создаваться новый объект.
Так и задумывалось?

Comment: Я лишь указал, как делать, чтоб срабатывали сигналы. Вариант передачи QMainWindow как родительский объект имеет право на жизнь, но нужно понимать, что все эти объекты будут удалены только когда будет удален QMainWindow, то есть, скорее всего при закрытие программы. В данной задаче, скорее всего будет достаточно создать один экземпляр TransportMail, сделать его членом класса и просто повторно использовать.

Comment: Можно создавать его не в куче, а так: 
`TransportMail tm;
    QObject::connect(&tm, SIGNAL (sendmail_sig(int)), ui->lcdNumberSendMail, SLOT (display(int)));

    tm.email_transport ("/home/alexandr/mutt/mail_shablon_dgis.html", "");`
Но тогда объект будет существовать только до конца работы функции.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш `TransportMail tm;` создается локально и существует только в пределах конструктора. Так дело не пойдет - создавайте его на куче при помощи `new`.

Comment: Сделал так, но результата не достиг, описание поправил.

Comment: @shaman888 Вам нужно в вашем классе создать поле типа TransportMail*, _ОДИН_РАЗ_ в конструкторе вызвать new (и записать результат в это поле), чтобы создать экземпляр на куче, и затем всякий раз работать с этим экземпляром.

Сейчас вы создаете два разных экземпляра. Прорабатывайте учебник с начала, а не с середины.